# Fast way of converting float of range -1 to 1 to short?

Tags: c, objective-c, audio, audio-recording

I need to repeatedly convert 1024+ consecutive 4 byte floats (range -1 to 1) to 2 byte shorts (range -32768 to 32767) and write to disk.

Currently I do this with a loop:

```
short v = 0;
for (unsigned int sample = 0; sample < length; sample++) 
{
    v = (short)(inbuffer[sample * 2] * 32767.0f);
    fwrite(&v, 2, 1, file);
}
```

And this works, but the floating point calc and loop is expensive. Is there any way this could be optimized?

Comment: Warning: if -1.0 translates to -32768 and 0.0 translates to 0, then +1.0 should translate to +32768, which is not in the `short` range.

Comment: Perhaps the OP means "from -1 up to but not including 1". Even so, floating-point rounding errors could cause trouble. Maybe it'd be better to save the calculation temporarily in an `int` and then check its value before storing it in a `float`.

Comment: Good point, -32767 to 32767 should be fine.

Comment: This question is a *perfect* example of why questions should include full context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
short v = 0;
for (unsigned int sample = 0; sample < length; sample++) 
{
    v = (short)(inbuffer[sample * 2] * 32767.0f);
    // The problem is not here-------^^^^^^^^^^^
    fwrite(&v, 2, 1, file);        
    // it is here ^^^^^^^
}
```

A typical Mac (objective-c tag, or are we talking about iphone here?) can do *billions* of float multiplications per second. fwrite however is a library call, which follows some indirections to write its data to some buffer and possibly flush it. It is better to fill your own buffer in a batch:

```
short v[SZ] = 0;
// make sure SZ is always > length, or allocate a working buffer on the heap.
for (unsigned int sample = 0; sample < length; sample++) 
{
    v[sample] = (short)(inbuffer[sample * 2] * 32767.0f);
}
fwrite(v,sizeof(v),1,file);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought the repeated calls to `fwrite` would be the expensive part. How about:

```
short outbuffer[length]; // note: you'll have to malloc this if length isn't constant and you're not using a version of C that supports dynamic arrays.
for (unsigned int sample = 0; sample < length; sample++) 
{
    outbuffer[sample] = (short)(inbuffer[sample * 2] * 32767.0f);
}
fwrite(outbuffer, sizeof *outbuffer, length, file);
```

Comment: Even if he has dynamic arrays it would not be a good idea to use them in a context where you don't know a bound on the size. Beware stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, that the bottleneck of your loop may be not short to float conversion but writing output to file - try to move file output outside the loop

```
short v = 0;
short outbuffer = // create outbuffer of required size
for (unsigned int sample = 0; sample < length; sample++) 
{
    outbuffer[sample] = (short)(inbuffer[sample * 2] * 32767.0f);
}

fwrite(outbuffer, 2, sizeof(outbuffer), file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
out[i] = table[((uint32_t *)in)[i]>>16];
```

where `table` is a lookup table that maps the upper 16 bits of an IEEE float to the `int16_t` value you want. However that will lose some precision. You'd need to keep and use 23 bits (1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and 14 mantissa bits) for full precision, and that means a 16 MB table, which will kill cache coherency and thus performance.

Are you sure that the floating point conversions are slow? As long as you're using `fwrite` that way, you're spending a good 50-100 times as much cpu time in `fwrite` as on floating point arithmetic. If you deal with this issue and the code is still too slow, you could use an approach of adding a magic bias and reading off the mantissa bits to convert to `int16_t` instead of multiplying by 32767.0. That might or might not be faster.